# HTTP Client in Python 3 - no cookies send

Tags: python, http, cookies

Just started working with HTTP in Python. I thought it would be nice to be platform independent in contrast to scripts using curl or wget, but I get crazy with it...
What is state-of-the-art-anyway? Request? urllib2? With/without "openers" ?

whatever, the request seems to work somewhat, but I get redirected to a "enable cookies" page. heres what I use. I tried to enable http debug, but it did not show the request/response at all?!

edit: The names are not key1, key2, of course - the URL is not some.page.com - I thought that was obvious, sorry.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import http.client
http.client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

post = {'key1': 'value1',
        'key2':'Value2',
       }
url = 'http://some.page.com'

req = urllib2.Request(url,urllib.parse.urlencode(post).encode('ascii'))
req.addheaders = [
    ('Cookie','key1=value1;key2=value2;')
    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'),
    ('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    ('Content-Length','42')
]

resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
with open('out.htm', 'w') as f:
    f.write(resp.read().decode(f.encoding))
    f.close()
```

Comment: The `requests` library is probably the most user-friendly.

Comment: "enable cookies" may mean that server expects cookies with specific  names - it don't have to be `key1`, `key2`. Maybe server sends to you cookies with this names. Check cookies in response.